# GeoNodes. Random Rotation from normals

Tags: normals, geometry-nodes

Let's say I have a log and I need to place moss or lichen on it. I make a bunch of nodes as in the screenshot below. But how do I make this moss rotate along the conditional Z-axis, not global, but the axes of the log normals?

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Attribute Randomize` node will fill the specified attribute with random values, but cannot (by itself) account for the existing state of the attribute. To take the initial rotation into account, you'll want the `Point Rotate` node.

In the below example, `rot_offset` is a custom attribute filled by `Attribute Randomize` that is used as an offset from the initial (normal-aligned) rotation. You can name it something different if you'd like. Set the min/max bounds on this attribute to change the range of random rotation.

[image: geo_nodes]

Note that if you want `rot_offset` to be considered in tangent space (treating the surface normal as positive z), you'll have to choose "Point" instead of "Object" in the `Point Rotate` node.

Comment: Yeach! This is exactly what I need! THANK YOU so MUCH!